# SQL Server Backup Jobs Failing. The error seems to be related to MaximumErrorCount, but I am not sure how to fix value or if changing it will resolve?

Tags: sql-server-2016, jobs

My backup jobs are failing with following error when check it's history. I have already checked this link regarding maximumerrorcount value: [SQL Server 2008 - Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250648/sql-server-2008-change-the-maximumerrorcount-or-fix-the-errors).

At this point I'm not sure what to do if maximumerrorcount is only masking the actual problem.

Log job history (DB_TaxExemption_BKP.Subplan_1):

> Step ID 1 Server INHOUSE-DB Job Name DB_TaxExemption_BKP.Subplan_1
> Step Name Subplan_1 Duration 00:00:00 Sql Severity 0 Sql Message ID 0
> Operator Emailed Operator Net sent Operator Paged Retries Attempted 0
> Message Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE. Microsoft (R)
> SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 14.0.1000.169 for 64-bit
> Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved. Started: 10:12:00
> PM Error: 2022-03-30 22:12:00.47 Code: 0xC00291EC Source:
> {4D6AAF94-D3FC-4873-9F66-E35E323A6BEE} Execute SQL Task Description:
> Failed to acquire connection "Local server connection". Connection may
> not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions
> on this connection. End Error Warning: 2022-03-30 22:12:00.47 Code:
> 0x80019002 Source: OnPreExecute Description: SSIS Warning Code
> DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED. The Execution method succeeded, but
> the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1);
> resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches
> the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the
> MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors. End Warning Error: 2022-03-30
> 22:12:00.48 Code: 0xC0024104 Source: Back Up Database (Full)
> Description: The Execute method on the task returned error code
> 0x80131904 (Login failed for user 'backupuser'.). The Execute method
> must succeed, and indicate the result using an "out" parameter. End
> Error ## Heading ##Error: 2022-03-30 22:12:00.48 Code: 0xC0024104
> Source: {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX} Description: The
> Execute method on the task returned error code 0x80131904 (Login
> failed for user 'backupuser'.). The Execute method must succeed, and
> indicate the result using an "out" parameter. End Error Warning:
> 2022-03-30 22:12:00.48 Code: 0x80019002 Source: OnPostExecute
> Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED. The
> Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2)
> reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs
> when the number of errors reaches the number specified in
> MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors. End
> Warning DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
> Started: 10:12:00 PM Finished: 10:12:00 PM Elapsed: 0.219 seconds. The
> package execution failed. The step failed

I know for sure that the user for this backup job is sysadmin and it is not locked out all rights are grated. And this is production so I cannot take many risks. What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you try to execute the backup statement from SSMS instead of maintenance plan?
You will get a clearer message on the actual error.

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log. There should be a message with more details about the cause of "Login failed for user 'backupuser'" error, which is why the backup failed. Add that to your question.

Comment: You are using a SSMS maintenance plan. Try to look up for errors in the maintenace plan not in the sql server agent job history.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a SSMS maintenance plan. Try to look up for errors in the maintenace plan not in the sql server agent job history.

You will find the true error.

[image]

(written as answer because i can't paste images on the comments)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly to me this part screams your issue Login failed for user 'backupuser'.

So either the job is trying to login with that user and the user doesn't exist OR the user is not a backup operator potentially and can't initiate those tasks. I know it sounds silly but I've had sysadmins that couldn't run backup jobs without backup operator role.